# Python union(), difference() methods in C

Tags: python, c, methods

Is there any methods in C standard libraries making the same thing with union() or difference() methods in Python? I have googled some, but find nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not in C, but in c++ : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in [`klib`](https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib), a C-based library. You could think about how you might mimic a set of elements with the keys of a hash table, and how you could implement set operations once you have hash tables built for each set.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard libraries do not implement set operators (as stated in response to [this prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179605/is-there-an-equivalent-in-c-of-pythons-set?rq=1)).  [This prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309669/need-c-library-that-implements-set-operations) suggests `pblset` as an alternative, and I'm sure there are others, but that's not a direct answer to your question (the direct answer is "no").  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252667/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-sets-in-c?rq=1) addresses array comparisons using a hash table.  In that same vein, responses to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406097/efficient-algorithm-to-find-a-maximum-common-subset-of-two-sets?rq=1) explain how to implement intersection using hashes.